# alembic generation of materialized view

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

TL;DR: How do I get alembic to understand and generate SQL for materialized views created in sqlalchemy?

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and also using alembic with postgres. To get a materialized view working with sqlalchemy, I followed a [nice post](http://www.jeffwidman.com/blog/847/using-sqlalchemy-to-create-and-manage-postgresql-materialized-views/) on the topic. I used it heavily, with just a few minor divergences (the article uses flask-sqlalchemy as well, however the complete code example uses sqlalchemy's declarative base directly instead).

```
class ActivityView(db.Model):
    __table__ = create_materialized_view(
        'activity_view',
        db.select([
            Activity.id.label('id'),
            Activity.name.label('name'),
            Activity.start_date.label('start_date'),
        ]).where(
            db.and_(
                Activity.start_date != None,
                Activity.start_date <=
                    datetime_to_str(datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC) + timedelta(hours=48))
            )
        )
    )

    @classmethod
    def refresh(cls, concurrently=True):
        refresh_materialized_view(cls.__table__.fullname, concurrently)

db.Index('activity_view_index',
         ActivityView.__table__.c.id, ActivityView.__table__.c.start_date,
         unique=True)
```

The `create_materialized_view` and `refresh_materialized_view` methods are taken straight from the blog post.

Note that the example above has been greatly simplified and probably seems silly because of my simplifications, ***but the real idea I want to get at is how do I get alembic to translate this view to a series of alembic operations during a migration***?

When I run tests, the code runs fine, the view gets generated fine and everything works. When alembic runs it doesn't do anything with the view. So what I end up doing is copying the SQL that the tests emit for the materialized view into the alembic migrations/versions file and just end up executing that directly as:

```
op.execute(activities_view_sql)
```

Similarly, I do the same direct SQL execution when generating the unique index on the materialized view.

Unfortunately my approach is error prone and creates seemingly unnecessary code duplication.

Is there a way to get alembic to understand my `ActivityView` so that any time it changes, alembic will know how to update the view?

Thanks much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever figure this one out? Starting down this path today...

Answer (score 5):

Although the question doesn't specifically call out using PostgreSQL, the post that it is based on targeted materialized views in PostgeSQL, so this answer also targets an add on package called [alembic_utils](https://github.com/olirice/alembic_utils), which is based on alembic [ReplaceableObjects](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects) that adds support for autogenerating a larger number of PostgreSQL entity types, including *functions*, *views*, *materialized views*, *triggers*, and *policies*.

To setup, you create your materialized view in the following way;

```py
from alembic_utils.pg_materialized_view import PGMaterializedView

actview = PGMaterializedView (
    schema="public",
    signature="activity_view",
    definition="select ...",
    with_data=True
)
```

You could base the `definition` off static SQL or compiled version of sqlalchemy code.

Then in your *alembic* `env.py`:

```py
from foo import actview
from alembic_utils.replaceable_entity import register_entities

register_entities([actview])
```

Alembic will now autogenerate migrations when the materialized view is updated in code.

EDIT: 10/10/2023 - It should be noted that alemic_utils will not automatically manage indexes you have on the materialized view, these need to be managed manually. Refer: https://github.com/olirice/alembic_utils/pull/46 for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to add SQLAlchemy ORM query instead of raw SQL query in the definiton ?

Comment: You could construct it as an ORM query and then convert it to string based SQL statement using `.compile()`

Comment: I have a problem in which I'm trying to create a table and the view based on this table on the same migration. Using the above structure makes alembic correctly detect both Objects to be created, however when it is time to create the view it fails saying that the table does not yet exist. Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: @DaniloFilippo, alembic migration generation isn't perfect, you may still have to make some modifications to the script generated to make sure it is being done in the correct order. Otherwise, check to make sure they are referencing the same schema.

Comment: @PeterHenry I posted a more detailed version of my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399029/create-table-and-view-in-the-same-migration-in-sqlalchemy. Would you mind taking a look and see what you think? I do think the problem is that alembic is trying to create things in the wrong order, but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: @DaniloFilippo, sorry for the delay in responding, I experienced a similar issue with functions/triggers. I posted a response in against your question linked above.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: Just write the view migration manually. It doesn't seem there is reasonable support for view autogeneration.

EDIT: It's possible there is a way to autogenerate view migrations now. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72829474/2839862

I think the easiest way around this is to not rely on Alembic to autogenerate the view for you. Instead, you can instruct it to ignore views like this, in your Alembic `env.py`:

```py
def include_object(obj, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if obj.info.get("is_view", False):
        return False

    return True

...

def run_migrations_offline():
...
    context.configure(url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True, include_object=include_object)

...

def run_migrations_online():
    ....
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata, include_object=include_object)
```

The `is_view` flag is set by my custom `View` base class:

```
class View(Model):
    @classmethod
    def _init_table(cls, sub_cls):
        table: sa.Table = Model._init_table(sub_cls)

        if table is None:
            return table

        table.info["is_view"] = True
        return table
```

When automatic generation ignores the view, you can then add the appropriate commands to your migration manually:

```py
activities = table(
    "activities",
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer()),
    ...
)

view_query = (
    select(
        [
            activities.c.id,
        ]
    )
    .select_from(activities)
)

def upgrade():
    view_query_string = str(view_query.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))

    op.execute(f"CREATE VIEW activity_view AS {view_query_string}")

def downgrade():
    op.execute("DROP VIEW activity_view")
```

Two important points:

1. code duplication is not always a bad thing - you can think of migrations as more of a version control tool, than regular code. Your version history should not depend on the current state of the codebase
2. manually-written migrations are arguably more error prone than generated ones, but you can partially alleviate this by running your migrations in tests for production applications. Also, just inspecting the resulting DB schema should help.